# Why is the neuter perniciosius used in this sentence?

Tags: grammar-choice, augustinus

In *[Confessions](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/augustine/conf1.shtml)* (1.18.29), Augustine writes:

> *quasi vero quemlibet inimicum hominem perniciosius sentiat quam ipsum
> odium quo in eum inritatur, aut vastet quisquam persequendo alium
> gravius quam cor suum vastat inimicando.*

I understand this as:

> As if, indeed, someone should think an enemy more pernicious than the
> very hatred by which he's irritated with him...

But if that's correct, I would have expected the masculine accusative *perniciosiorem*, instead of the neuter *[perniciosius](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=perniciosius&la=la#lexicon)*.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Formally, *perniciosius* can be either a comparative adverb or a comparative adjective in the nom./acc. sg. neuter. Syntactically the neuter seems to fit better here:

> as if he might think any enemy to be a more pernicious thing than the very hatred...

The adverbial reading seems to work less well -- it would mean "as if he might feel any enemy more perniciously than...", but it's not clear to me what that means and *sentio* doesn't generally seem to take human objects in this way.

Comment: +1, but is it common to use n. _sing._ in that way, as opposed to the plural? If so, is that late Latin?

Comment: @Rafael "Varium et mutabile semper femina" was fine with Vergil. It's not very common but it is certainly classical. The meaning is different in the two numbers: a singular neuter is a single object, a plural one is closer to a continuous mass.